# How do I access UserManager outside of the Identity project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web, identityserver4, webapi

I have three projects that I'll refer to as Identity, SPA, and API.

The Identity project handles authentication and authorization using IdentityServer4.  SPA is a single page application that uses Identity to authenticate and communicates with the API using the token provided by Identity.  API uses Identity to provide authorization based on the token passed from SPA.

I want to access the ApplicationUser data in Identity using UserManager.  The Identity database is shared with API, but I'm trying to use the Identity API to access the additional user data.  If I move the Identity to its own database, the application wouldn't change except for the database reference in the settings.

So my question is this: How do I access UserManager to update the additional user data from API?

Comment: I had to inject all of the ApplicationDbContext classes inside OWIN startup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68660293/how-to-use-identityserver4-usermanager-method-from-another-project-api/68665828#68665828

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to add the User Manager to an additional project outside of Identity:

```
var userStoreType = typeof(UserStore<,,,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(User), typeof(IdentityRole<Guid>), typeof(MyDbContext), typeof(Guid));
var roleStoreType = typeof(RoleStore<,,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(IdentityRole<Guid>), typeof(MyDbContext), typeof(Guid));

services.TryAddScoped(typeof(IUserStore<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(User)), userStoreType);
services.TryAddScoped(typeof(IRoleStore<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(IdentityRole<Guid>)), roleStoreType);

services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<User>, PasswordHasher<User>>();
services.TryAddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
services.TryAddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();

services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<User>>();
```