# How to use IdentityServer4 UserManager method from another project api

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, .net-5

I have an identity server project located in the directory `D:\IdentityServer` and have an api project located in the directory `D:\WebApi` - web api is using another database and authenticated by identity server.

I've tried:

```
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;


public GetProductsHandler(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager) 
{}
```

but I get

> Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[TestService.Queries.GetProductsHandler`1[TestSerice.Dtos.ProductsDto]]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples.

How can I call UserManager (from Identity Server) to get a user's information by username or use to get the user's role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your API, you need to inject all of the identity objects inside Startup.cs:

```
        services.AddScoped<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>, UserValidator<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.AddScoped<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>, PasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>, PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.AddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
        services.AddScoped<IRoleValidator<ApplicationRole>, RoleValidator<ApplicationRole>>();
        services.AddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
        services.AddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.AddScoped<ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator, TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>>();
        services.AddScoped<ApplicationUserManager>();
        services.AddScoped<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        services.AddScoped<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.AddScoped<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationUserStore>();
        services.AddScoped<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>, ApplicationRoleStore>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserConfirmation<ApplicationUser>, DefaultUserConfirmation<ApplicationUser>>();
        var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(typeof(ApplicationUser), typeof(ApplicationRole), services);
        identityBuilder.AddTokenProvider("Default", typeof(DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>));
```